# How to implement FIPS_mode() and FIPS_mode_set() in Python 3.6's ssl module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, fips

I am trying to implement the FIPS_mode and FIPS_mode_set functions in Python's ssl module since those are not present by default. [A patch](https://bugs.python.org/issue27592) for Python 3.4 has already been submitted and rejected due to various using reasons.

Using that patch as an inspiration, i made some modifications and added the following code in **ssl.py**:

```
try:
    from _ssl import FIPS_mode, FIPS_mode_set
except ImportError:
    pass
```

And the following code in **_ssl.c**:

```
#define EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS

#ifdef EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS


static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(PyObject *module) {
    return PyLong_FromLong(FIPS_mode());
}

static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(PyObject *module, int n) {
    if (FIPS_mode_set(n) == 0) {
        _setSSLError(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) , 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

#endif  //EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS

/* List of functions exported by this module. */
static PyMethodDef PySSL_methods[] = {
    _SSL__TEST_DECODE_CERT_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_ADD_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_BYTES_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_PSEUDO_BYTES_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_EGD_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_STATUS_METHODDEF
    _SSL_GET_DEFAULT_VERIFY_PATHS_METHODDEF
    _SSL_ENUM_CERTIFICATES_METHODDEF
    _SSL_ENUM_CRLS_METHODDEF
    _SSL_TXT2OBJ_METHODDEF
    _SSL_NID2OBJ_METHODDEF
    _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF
    _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF
    {NULL,                  NULL}            /* Sentinel */
};
```

This however is throwing the following errors:

```
./Modules/_ssl.c:5060:5: error: '_SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF' undeclared here (not in a function)
     _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF

./Modules/_ssl.c:5061:5: error: expected '}' before '_SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF'
     _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF

./Modules/_ssl.c:4641:1: warning: '_ssl_FIPS_mode_impl' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]  _ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(PyObject
*module) { 

./Modules/_ssl.c:4646:1: warning: '_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl' defined but not used [-Wunused-function] 
_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(PyObject *module, int n) {  ^
```

I am pretty sure i am missing something extremely trivial here but i cant seem to figure out what exactly. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**Update:**

A big shoutout to **@CristiFati** who pointed out that i was missing the macros which needed to be defined, I was able to solve this. In case someone else needs to implement FIPS Mode in Python 3.6, add the following code:

**_ssl.c:**

```
static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(PyObject *module) {
    return PyLong_FromLong(FIPS_mode());
}

static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(PyObject *module, int n) {
    if (FIPS_mode_set(n) == 0) {
        _setSSLError(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) , 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef PySSL_methods[] = {
    _SSL__TEST_DECODE_CERT_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_ADD_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_BYTES_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_PSEUDO_BYTES_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_EGD_METHODDEF
    _SSL_RAND_STATUS_METHODDEF
    _SSL_GET_DEFAULT_VERIFY_PATHS_METHODDEF
    _SSL_ENUM_CERTIFICATES_METHODDEF
    _SSL_ENUM_CRLS_METHODDEF
    _SSL_TXT2OBJ_METHODDEF
    _SSL_NID2OBJ_METHODDEF
    _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF
    _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF
    {NULL,                  NULL}            /* Sentinel */
};
```

**_ssl.c.h:**

```
PyDoc_STRVAR(_ssl_FIPS_mode__doc__,
"FIPS Mode");

#define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF    \
    {"FIPS_mode", (PyCFunction)_ssl_FIPS_mode, METH_NOARGS, _ssl_FIPS_mode__doc__},    

static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(PyObject *module);

static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode(PyObject *module, PyObject *Py_UNUSED(ignored))
{
    return _ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(module);
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_doc__,
"FIPS Mode Set");

#define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF    \
    {"FIPS_mode_set", (PyCFunction)_ssl_FIPS_mode_set, METH_O, _ssl_FIPS_mode_set_doc__},   

static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(PyObject *module, int n);

static PyObject *
_ssl_FIPS_mode_set(PyObject *module, PyObject *arg)
{
    PyObject *return_value = NULL;
    int n;

    if (!PyArg_Parse(arg, "i:FIPS_mode_set", &n)) {
        goto exit;
    }
    return_value = _ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(module, n);

exit:
    return return_value;
}
```

**ssl.py:**

```
try:
    from _ssl import FIPS_mode, FIPS_mode_set
    print('successful import')
except ImportError as e:
    print('error in importing')
    print(e)
```

Comment: Just looked at the edits.... **never** add the (an) answer as part of a question. Add another answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I noticed that since *Python **3.5***, the *${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Modules/_ssl.c* structure has changed (got "a little bit" more structured and also contains generated code), compared to the ***3.4*** version that I submitted the patch to (**[[Python.Bugs]: FIPS_mode() and FIPS_mode_set() functions in Python (ssl)](https://bugs.python.org/issue27592)**). 
Basically, every entry in the *PySSL_methods* array is no longer defined on the spot, but indirectly, via a preprocessor macro. 
You acted according to the new *standard*, but forgot to define the macros.

In order to fix the problem:

1. Define the 2 macros for the *PyMethodDef* entries (**inside** `#ifdef EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS`):

   ```c
   // ...

   }

   #define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF    \
       {"FIPS_mode", (PyCFunction)_ssl_FIPS_mode_impl, METH_NOARGS, NULL},

   #define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF    \
       {"FIPS_mode_set", (PyCFunction)_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl, METH_O, NULL},

   #endif  // EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS

   // ...
   ```
2. "*Protect*" the new macros by an ***#ifdef*** clause (similarly to where they were defined) when defining *PySSL_methods* (so that if the *EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS* macro isn't defined, you won't get a compile error):

   ```
   // ...

   _SSL_NID2OBJ_METHODDEF
   #ifdef EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS
   _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF
   _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF
   #endif  // EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS
   {NULL,                  NULL}            /* Sentinel */

   // ...
   ```

**Notes**:

- Since you didn't define the *docstring*s, I filled them with *NULL*s (*PyMethodDef*'s last member). That will result in syntactically correct code, but I'm not sure how will it behave at runtime, when you'll run `help()` on any of the 2 functions. If it segfaults, copy the definitions from the patch or define some dummy strings using *PyDoc_STRVAR* (and recompile, of course)
- Although this is closer to the *standard* than the original patch, it's not quite there, as *OP* (@HussainAliAkbar) shown in the (2<sup>nd</sup>) edit. Things are a little bit more complicated (also involving *${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Modules/clinic/_ssl.c.h*). See the next update section below

---

#### Update *#0*

- I took some time to check what's the deal with that *clinic* folder. It's [[Python.Docs]: Argument Clinic How-To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html#argument-clinic-how-to). I consider it a **major improvement** because it spares the developer writing the argument parsing code (involving *PyArg_**, *Py*_Check* funcs) in every function ("*monkey work*")
- I spent some hours, but I managed to do things "by the book" (at least, I think so)

*Python-3.6.4-ssl_fips.diff*:

```diff
--- Python-3.6.4/Modules/_ssl.c.orig    2018-07-27 19:10:06.131999999 +0300
+++ Python-3.6.4/Modules/_ssl.c 2018-07-27 20:32:15.531999999 +0300
@@ -4789,6 +4789,46 @@
     return result;
 }
 
+#if defined(EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS)
+
+unsigned char _fips_table_sig[0x0C] = {0x21, 0x7A, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x75, 0x72, 0x20, 0x49, 0x54, 0x41, 0x46, 0x00};
+
+/*[clinic input]
+_ssl.FIPS_mode
+
+Return 1 (!=0) if FIPS mode is enabled, 0 otherwise.
+[clinic start generated code]*/
+
+static PyObject *
+_ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(PyObject *module)
+/*[clinic end generated code: output=89f5a88ec715a291 input=52e4e5fdd1f555c7]*/
+{
+    return PyLong_FromLong(FIPS_mode());
+}
+
+/*[clinic input]
+_ssl.FIPS_mode_set
+    mode: int
+    /
+
+Try to set the FIPS mode to 'mode' (int).
+
+Return nothing. Raise SSLError when enabling FIPS mode fails.
+[clinic start generated code]*/
+
+static PyObject *
+_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(PyObject *module, int mode)
+/*[clinic end generated code: output=70e3e9f3bb4fce65 input=899c21a986720235]*/
+{
+if (FIPS_mode_set(mode) == 0) {
+        _setSSLError(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL), 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
+        return NULL;
+    }
+    Py_RETURN_NONE;
+}
+
+#endif  // EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS
+
 #ifdef _MSC_VER
 
 static PyObject*
@@ -5055,6 +5095,8 @@
     _SSL_ENUM_CRLS_METHODDEF
     _SSL_TXT2OBJ_METHODDEF
     _SSL_NID2OBJ_METHODDEF
+    _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF
+    _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF
     {NULL,                  NULL}            /* Sentinel */
 };
 
--- Python-3.6.4/Modules/clinic/_ssl.c.h.orig   2018-07-27 19:10:48.067999999 +0300
+++ Python-3.6.4/Modules/clinic/_ssl.c.h    2018-07-27 20:31:04.507999999 +0300
@@ -1062,6 +1062,61 @@
     return return_value;
 }
 
+#if defined(EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS)
+
+PyDoc_STRVAR(_ssl_FIPS_mode__doc__,
+"FIPS_mode($module, /)\n"
+"--\n"
+"\n"
+"Return 1 (!=0) if FIPS mode is enabled, 0 otherwise.");
+
+#define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF    \
+    {"FIPS_mode", (PyCFunction)_ssl_FIPS_mode, METH_NOARGS, _ssl_FIPS_mode__doc__},
+
+static PyObject *
+_ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(PyObject *module);
+
+static PyObject *
+_ssl_FIPS_mode(PyObject *module, PyObject *Py_UNUSED(ignored))
+{
+    return _ssl_FIPS_mode_impl(module);
+}
+
+#endif /* defined(EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS) */
+
+#if defined(EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS)
+
+PyDoc_STRVAR(_ssl_FIPS_mode_set__doc__,
+"FIPS_mode_set($module, mode, /)\n"
+"--\n"
+"\n"
+"Try to set the FIPS mode to \'mode\' (int).\n"
+"\n"
+"Return nothing. Raise SSLError when enabling FIPS mode fails.");
+
+#define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF    \
+    {"FIPS_mode_set", (PyCFunction)_ssl_FIPS_mode_set, METH_O, _ssl_FIPS_mode_set__doc__},
+
+static PyObject *
+_ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(PyObject *module, int mode);
+
+static PyObject *
+_ssl_FIPS_mode_set(PyObject *module, PyObject *arg)
+{
+    PyObject *return_value = NULL;
+    int mode;
+
+    if (!PyArg_Parse(arg, "i:FIPS_mode_set", &mode)) {
+        goto exit;
+    }
+    return_value = _ssl_FIPS_mode_set_impl(module, mode);
+
+exit:
+    return return_value;
+}
+
+#endif /* defined(EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS) */
+
 #if defined(_MSC_VER)
 
 PyDoc_STRVAR(_ssl_enum_certificates__doc__,
@@ -1161,6 +1216,14 @@
     #define _SSL_RAND_EGD_METHODDEF
 #endif /* !defined(_SSL_RAND_EGD_METHODDEF) */
 
+#ifndef _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF
+    #define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF
+#endif /* !defined(_SSL_FIPS_MODE_METHODDEF) */
+
+#ifndef _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF
+    #define _SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF
+#endif /* !defined(_SSL_FIPS_MODE_SET_METHODDEF) */
+
 #ifndef _SSL_ENUM_CERTIFICATES_METHODDEF
     #define _SSL_ENUM_CERTIFICATES_METHODDEF
 #endif /* !defined(_SSL_ENUM_CERTIFICATES_METHODDEF) */
@@ -1168,4 +1231,4 @@
 #ifndef _SSL_ENUM_CRLS_METHODDEF
     #define _SSL_ENUM_CRLS_METHODDEF
 #endif /* !defined(_SSL_ENUM_CRLS_METHODDEF) */
-/*[clinic end generated code: output=a8b184655068c238 input=a9049054013a1b77]*/
+/*[clinic end generated code: output=94d0ec4213d44124 input=a9049054013a1b77]*/
--- Python-3.6.4/Lib/ssl.py.orig    2018-07-27 19:10:29.827999999 +0300
+++ Python-3.6.4/Lib/ssl.py 2018-03-28 23:30:35.065667344 +0300
@@ -114,6 +114,11 @@
     # LibreSSL does not provide RAND_egd
     pass
 
+try:
+    from _ssl import FIPS_mode, FIPS_mode_set
+except ImportError:
+    # Compiled without FIPS functions support
+    pass 
 
 from _ssl import HAS_SNI, HAS_ECDH, HAS_NPN, HAS_ALPN, HAS_TLSv1_3
 from _ssl import _OPENSSL_API_VERSION
--- Python-3.6.4/setup.py.orig  2018-07-27 19:09:33.763999999 +0300
+++ Python-3.6.4/setup.py   2018-03-28 23:30:35.061667315 +0300
@@ -862,6 +862,7 @@
             ssl_libs is not None):
             exts.append( Extension('_ssl', ['_ssl.c'],
                                    include_dirs = ssl_incs,
+                                   define_macros = [("EXPORT_FIPSMODE_FUNCS", None)],
                                    library_dirs = ssl_libs,
                                    libraries = ['ssl', 'crypto'],
                                    depends = ['socketmodule.h']), )
```

**Notes**:

- That is a *diff* (note that it's **outside *${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}***). See [[SO]: Run/Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *utrunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out)
- Source baseline is ***v3.6.4*** (as pointed by the file name)
- 4 files are modified:

  - *${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Modules/_ssl.c* - contains both manual and generated (as you guessed, by the *Argument Clinic*) changes (generated pieces easy to spot from comments)
  - *${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Modules/clinic/_ssl.c.h* - contains generated code only
  - The other 2 contain manual changes

I also tested the changes (at one point I used the *OpenSSL* version that I've built for [[SO]: How to enable FIPS mode for libcrypto and libssl packaged with Python? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382743/4788546))

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049493537]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./py364-nofips/lib ./py364-nofips/bin/python3 -c "import ssl;print(ssl.FIPS_mode())"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'FIPS_mode'
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049493537]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=py364-fips/lib py364-fips/bin/python3 -c "import ssl;print(ssl.FIPS_mode(), ssl.FIPS_mode_set(0), ssl.FIPS_mode());print(ssl.FIPS_mode_set(1), ssl.FIPS_mode())"
> 0 None 0
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ssl.SSLError: error:0F06D065:common libcrypto routines:FIPS_mode_set:fips mode not supported (_ssl.c:4822)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q049493537]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=py364-fips/lib:../q049320993/ssl/build/lib py364-fips/bin/python3 -c "import ssl;print(ssl.FIPS_mode(), ssl.FIPS_mode_set(0), ssl.FIPS_mode());print(ssl.FIPS_mode_set(1), ssl.FIPS_mode())"
> 0 None 0
> None 1
> ```

Might also look over [[SO]: OpenSSL FIPS_mode_set not working in Python cryptography library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58311407/4788546).

Comment: Thank you so much yet again! I managed to find the file where the macros  were defined (Modules/clinic/_ssl.c.h) after you told me about them and so i defined them there in order to follow the new standard. I'll post the details in the answer. Thank you once again!

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to specify that in order to be rigorous you should place them in *clinic/\_ssl.c.h*. But it works either way (if you place them in *\_ssl.c* directly). I'll update the answer.

Comment: alright great! I have already updated my question and posted the complete solution below as well in case someone else faces the same problem.