# ./python: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

I need to try python 3.7 with openssl-1.1.1 in Ubuntu 16.04. Both python and openssl versions are pre-release. Following instructions on how to statistically link openssl to python in [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location), I downloaded the source for [opnssl-1.1.1](https://www.openssl.org/source/). 
Then navigate to the source code for openssl and execute:

```
./config
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then, edit `Modules/Setup.dist` to uncomment the following lines:

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Then download [python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370b4/) source code. Then, navigate inside the source code and execute:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

After I execute `make install` I got this error at the end of the terminal output:

```
./python: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
generate-posix-vars failed
Makefile:596: recipe for target 'pybuilddir.txt' failed
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

I could not figure out what is the problem and what I need to do.

Comment: you forgot to uncomment `_socket socketmodule.c` too but that won't solve your problem AFAIK

Comment: Your SSL libs -- if they're in `/usr/local/lib` (default location if you don't pass any other arguments to `./config` when compiling), make sure that location is in your `/etc/ld.so.conf`, and that you've run `ldconfig` to update the cache tracking shared library locations.

Comment: Beyond that, it's also helpful to check output of `ldd` to figure out why an executable can't be loaded.

Answer (score 7):

This has (should have) nothing to do with *Python* or *OpenSSL* versions.

*Python* build process, includes some steps when the newly built interpreter is launched, and attempts to load some of the newly built modules - including **extension modules** (which are written in *C* and are actually *shared objects* (*.so*s)).

When an *.so* is loaded, the loader must find (recursively) all the *.so* files that the *.so* needs (depends on), otherwise it won't be able to load it.

*Python* has some modules (e.g. *_ssl*.so*, *_hashlib*.so*) that depend on *OpenSSL* *lib*s. Since you built yours against *OpenSSL**1.1.1*** (the *lib* names differ from what comes by default on the system: typically ***1.0.****), the loader won't be able to use the default ones.

What you need to do, is instruct the loader (check [[Man7]: LD.SO(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for more details) where to look for "your" *OpenSSL* *lib*s (which are located under */usr/local/ssl/lib*). One way of doing that is adding their path in *${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}* *env var* (before building *Python*):

> ```bash
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/ssl/lib
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```

You might also want to take a look at [[Python.Docs]: Configure Python - Libraries options](https://docs.python.org/3/using/configure.html#libraries-options) (*--with-openssl*, *--with-openssl-rpath*).

Worth reading (probably):

- [[SO]: How to enable FIPS mode for libcrypto and libssl packaged with Python? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382743/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670925/4788546)

Answer (score 2):

What I have done to fix this :

```
./configure --with-ssl=./libssl --prefix=/subsystem
sed -i 's!^RUNSHARED=!RUNSHARED=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/own/libssl/lib!' Makefile
make
make install
```

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with export was not sufficient

Comment: I, too, was getting build errors with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH export, and this Makefile change worked for me. Centos 7, python 3.10.4

Comment: although having said that, I can't import ssl from the resulting python build

Comment: I had upvoted this, but should have downvoted. stackoverflow won't let me change my vote. The problem with this change is it prevents python's lib-dynload from being created.

Answer (score -1):

With Python-3.6.5 and openssl-1.1.0h i get stuck in the same problem. I have uncomment _socket socketmodule.c.